# Database designing - "1 table or 2 tables", "If 2 tables: create copy or join"

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design

I will be storing same structure of data of different nature in table(s).

**Scenario:** There will be a template of data that will be shown to customers on registration.

On registration the customers can edit the details and save it as their local settings. This will not impact the global template setting that was displayed to the customer initially.

I have few options now.

**Option # 1:** I can store all global and local settings in just one table

For customer registration page

```
select * from Settings where RegistrationID is null
```

For retrieving customer settings

```
select * from Settings where RegistrationID = {RegID}
```

Therefore every time new customers come for registration the system will use this growing table for retrieving the template (global) settings

**Option#2:** Storing global and local settings in separate tables
This will have following further options

**2.a)**
Copy all user settings in the local.Settings table for user for retreival. In this case the system will just refer to one table. This will have a lot of duplications for each registration.

```
    select * from local.Settings where RegistratioID = '{RegID}'
```

**2.b)**  Store only edited settings in local.Settings table and create another table to local.RegistrationSettings(RegistrationID,SettingID) for handling one to many relationship. In this case system will need to use union statement on global.Settings and local.Settings. Also I will have to make considerations of uniqueness of setting ID on both tables, which I think is manageable if I define a range for both tables.

```
select * from
   ((select * from global.Settings)  union all (select * from local.Settings where RegistationID = {RegID})) as s
inner join RegistrationSettings as r on r.SettingID = s.ID where r.RegistrationID = {RegID}
```

**Question**
Which one is the better option?
Is there any other way this could be handled?

Answer (score 0):

I'd think it's better to have two different tables, allowing you to have better control of your data and making your system more efficient.

Comment: Thanks for your response, What do you suggest for keeping copies into local of all settings(edit or no edit) vs using union for global(unedited) and local(edited). Option 2a) or 2b)